# Mongoose text search with diacriticSensitive

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mongoose query:

```
User.find(
    {
        $text: {
            $search: req.query.search,
            $diacriticSensitive: true
        }
    },
    {
        score: {
            $meta: "textScore"
        }
    }, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        next(err);
        return;
    }

    return res.json(results);
});
```

The query leads to the following error message:

```
Can't canonicalize query: BadValue extra fields in $text
```

When I remove the "$diacriticSensitive: true" part from the query I get no error message, but only get exact matches.

What I want is when the user searches for "USERNA", but only the user "USERNAME" is available, this result should also be shown with a low score.

I am using Mongoose 4.3.5 and MongoDB 3.0.3.

MongoDB supports this attribute, doesn't Mongoose support it?

Comment: What is the version of mongodb you used?

Comment: I am using Mongoose 4.3.5 and MongoDB 3.0.3.

Comment: I found it. My version of MongoDB does not provide this attribute! https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/text/

Comment: I tried it with newest mongo db version but it does not work either. :(

Answer (score 2):

Per [doc](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/), `$diacriticSensitive` option is enable in mongodb `v3.2`

---

For `articles` document

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d305dcc7ce7117db9b6da4"), "subject" : "Coffee Shopping", "author" : "efg", "view" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d305e9c7ce7117db9b6da5"), "subject" : "Coffee and cream", "author" : "efg", "view" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d305fec7ce7117db9b6da6"), "subject" : "Baking a cake", "author" : "abc", "view" : 50 }
```

Here are my test codes

```
var ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    subject: String,
    author: String,
    view: Number,
    score: Number,
});

ArticleSchema.index({subject: 'text'});
var article = mongoose.model('article', ArticleSchema);

function queryText() {
    article
        .find({$text: {$search: 'Coffee', $diacriticSensitive: true}}, 
                {score: {$meta: 'textScore'}})
        .exec(function(err, doc) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            else
                console.log(doc);
        });
}
```

Result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d305dcc7ce7117db9b6da4"), "subject" : "Coffee Shopping", "author" : "efg", "view" : 5, "score" : 0.75 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d305e9c7ce7117db9b6da5"), "subject" : "Coffee and cream", "author" : "efg", "view" : 10, "score" : 0.75 }
```

Comment: Thanks, found it out in the same second. :)

Comment: I tried it with newest mongo db version but it does not work either. :(

Comment: Can it be, that Mongoose does not provide it yet?

Comment: @user2500558, have you try to run this command `{
        $text: {
            $search: req.query.search,
            $diacriticSensitive: true
        }
    },
    {
        score: {
            $meta: "textScore"
        }
    }` in mongo shell, it does NOT work either?

Comment: @user2500558, the `$diacriticSensitive` is just one option for mongodb query, not related to mognoose. Per mongoose code, it just wrap this option into `find` query condition, then run the mongo native query...

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I get the error from above. I pass the following query into find method: `{ $text: { $search: req.query.searchtext, $diacriticSensitive: true } }, { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }`.

Comment: @user2500558, I have updated my answer with my test data and test code, please check it...please make sure `index({subject: 'text'});` is enabled ...

Comment: if you are using a recent version of mongoDB, say version higher than v3. you don't have to set `$diacriticSensitive` cos by default it is true.